# Unusual word order to fit a rhyming structure

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term for when a line of poetry has the words in an unusual/less natural order to fit into a rhyming structure?

> e.g. Your journey will end with the ending day, You never again will
> pass this way;

The second line would more commonly be phrased "You will never again pass this way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an example of the literary device known as *inversion*. There is a pretty comprehensive explanation of it here: https://literarydevices.com/inversion/

From that website:

> As a literary device, inversion refers to the reversal of the syntactically correct order of subjects, verbs, and objects in a sentence.

and

> It is also more common to find inversion in poetry than in prose because there the unnaturalness of inversion lends itself well to creating a poetic lilt. Poets might also choose to use inversion in order to create a rhyme or uphold a meter that would not work with the syntactically correct order of words.

And just a note about your last sentence: I think the second line actually would more commonly be phrased "You will never pass this way again." (At least that's how [Seals and Crofts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd6zYQPCgsc) would sing it.)

Comment: I think ending the line "way"  in the counterexample was to maintain the rhyme with "day", but not fit a likely meter

Comment: Yes, it was inversion “to create a rhyme.”

Answer (score 2):

**poetic license**

> n.
> The liberty taken by an artist or a writer in deviating from conventional form or fact to achieve a desired effect.
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=poetic%20license)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like **”Yoda Grammar”**.

Quoting https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/yoda-grammar/

> […] Carson also notes that although Yoda shifts around sentence elements, he doesn’t do so randomly. He tends to use **object-subject-verb word order**,* as in “Princess Leia, Han Solo digs,” […]

https://justpublishingadvice.com/star-wars-grammar-by-yoda/ provide this fun graphic.

￼

[image: yoda speak]

You could also say Yoda-esque or Yoda-speak. Or sounds like Yoda from Star Wars, etc.

Comment: From the link in my answer: “The character Yoda in Star Wars often speaks in inversion.”

Comment: @JLG it was your *inversion* answer that made me think of this one; though I hadn’t clicked the references til now. I liked your answer and upvoted it. I know we have some overlap here, but I am minded to keep this answer anyway.